# show the IP address of the device on a html page

Tags: html, flask, ip

I use the command below to get the IP addresses of my device:

`ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}'`

the output is something like this:

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.122.1
192.168.0.101
```

I'd like to show this result on a simple html file (which I developed as UI for my device / runs on local address using flask) as a text part to have an overview on the addresses whenever I turn the device on. (kinda redirecting the output of the command to a text object on html)

How can I achieve that?

Or, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, make the call to `ifconfig` with `subprocess` and return the output.

```
import subprocess
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    p = subprocess.Popen("ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```